# Crear una columna con base en el cumplimiento de una condicional en al menos una de varias columnas a comparar

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data

Quiero crear una columna en un DataFrame de Pandas con Python que devuelva un valor booleano (`True`, `False`) si se cumple una condición en al menos una de las columnas que se van a revisar.

En mi caso específico quiero crear la columna `TIENE_COMORBILIDAD` a partir de si en al menos una de las 10 columnas a revisar el valor es `"SI"`. En ese caso devolverá `True`. De lo contrario, si en ninguna columna tiene un valor `"SI"`, devolvería `False`.

El dataframe simplicado es este:

```
FECHA           TABAQUISMO          EPOC         OBESIDAD       DIABETES

30/04/2020        SI                 NO            NO               SI

30/04/2020        SI                 NO            SI               SI
```

Esto es lo que he intentado:

```
df["TIENE_COMORBILIDAD"] = df[['DIABETES',
       'EPOC', 'ASMA', 'INMUSUPR', 'HIPERTENSION', 'OTRA_COM',
       'CARDIOVASCULAR', 'OBESIDAD', 'RENAL_CRONICA', 'TABAQUISMO']].apply(lambda x: "SI" in str (x), axis = 1)
```

Pero la columna `"TIENE_COMORBILIDAD"` me devuelve valores `True` en todas las filas, y tras una revisión manual noté que ciertas columnas no tenían el valor "SI" en toda una fila.

¿Alguien conoce de una forma de hacerlo y que se logre la comparación de manera correcta?

Comment: El dataframe simplicado es este:

`df:

FECHA  TABAQUISMO   EPOC   OBESIDAD   DIABETES

30/04/2020        SI                 NO            NO               SI

30/04/2020        SI                 NO             SI                SI `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes hacerlo en dos pasos:

- Usas `pandas.DataFrame.eq` sobre las columnas objetivo para obtener que celdas tienen un `"SI"`.
- Aplicas `pandas.DataFrame.any` sobre la salida de `eq` y lo aplicas sobre las filas, eje 1. Con esto ya obtienes tu Serie de boleanos.

---

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'FECHA': ("10/03/2020", "10/03/2020", "10/03/2020"),
                   'DIABETES': ("NO", "NO", "NO"),
                   'EPOC': ("NO", "NO", "NO"),
                   'ASMA': ("SI", "NO", "NO"),
                   'INMUSUPR': ("NO", "NO", "NO"),
                   'HIPERTENSION': ("NO", "NO", "NO"),
                   'OTRA_COM': ("NO", "NO", "NO"),
                   'CARDIOVASCULAR':("NO", "NO", "NO"),
                   'OBESIDAD': ("NO", "NO", "NO"),
                   'RENAL_CRONICA': ("SI", "NO", "NO"),
                   'TABAQUISMO': ("NO", "NO", "SI")}
                   )

df["TIENE_COMORBILIDAD"] = df.iloc[:, 1:].eq("SI").any(axis=1)
```

> ```
> >>> df
>         FECHA DIABETES EPOC ASMA INMUSUPR HIPERTENSION OTRA_COM CARDIOVASCULAR OBESIDAD RENAL_CRONICA TABAQUISMO  TIENE_COMORBILIDAD
> 0  10/03/2020       NO   NO   SI       NO           NO       NO             NO       NO            SI         NO                True
> 1  10/03/2020       NO   NO   NO       NO           NO       NO             NO       NO            NO         NO               False
> 2  10/03/2020       NO   NO   NO       NO           NO       NO             NO       NO            NO         SI                True
> ```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Me funcionó de maravilla.